# ServiceURL is null when sending a message to a microsoft bot from slack after the update to v3

Tags: botframework

There seems an issue after the bot framework update to v3. When I run the echo dialog example from bot emulator, it works fine but when I publish the bot and call it via slack, it gives an error. On debugging, I found that Activity.serviceURL is null when the message is coming from slack. However, when it comes from bot emulator, the serviceURL is not null. I have followed the documentation for echo dialog [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dialogs.html) which throws null error for serviceURL when called from slack. Any idea on how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the configuration of your bot in botframework.com and choose version 3.0. You need to copy the Microsoft App ID and write it in your webconfig file, also you will need to generate a password for your app by clicking the button "Manage Microsoft App ID and password" that is in the configuration of your bot, when you have the password put it in MicrosoftAppPassword in your webconfig. Finally put some text on BotId, I think it is not relevant.